Isometry group of hyperbolic space
Let $\mathbb R^{n,1}$ be the space  $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ endowed with the bilinear form $$\langle x, y \rangle_{n,1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_iy_i -x_{n+1}y_{n+1}$$   We define the hyperboloid model  as $$\mathbb{H}^n = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+2} \mid \langle x, x\rangle_{n,1} = -1, x_{n+1}>0\}$$
We define  $$O(n, 1) = \{A \in GL(n+1, \mathbb{R}) \mid \langle Ax, Ay \rangle_{n,1} = \langle x, y \rangle_{n,1} \ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\}$$ We define $$O^+(n, 1) = \{A \in O(n,1)) \mid A(\mathbb{H}^n) = \mathbb{H}^n\}$$ and $\text{Isom}\ (\mathbb{H}^n) = O^+(n,1)$.
But in some references it is written that $\text{Isom}\ (\mathbb{H}^n) = O_o(n,1)$, the connected component containing the identity. My question: Is $O^+(n,1) = O_o(n,1)$? Please help.
I am adding references:

An Introduction to Geometric Topology, Martelli (See page 47)
Anosov Representations: Informal Lecture Motes (Page 43, paragraph- 5)


Your definition of the hyperboloid model is wrong. You have to take a connected component. And you should add references to the claims you are making. No good reference will exclude orientation reversing isometries.

@MoisheKohan I have edited now. Thanks

Well, Canary is simply wrong. Keep in mind, that these are just informal notes, as the title says. Presumably, if he ever publishes these, he will correct the mistake. If you feel like it, you can write to him and ask to make a correction.

@MoisheKohan So, $\text{Isom}\ (\mathbb{H}^n) = O^+(n,1)$?

Of course. And $O_o(n,1)$ is the unique index 2 subgroup of $O^+(n,1)$ consisting of orientation-preserving isometries. But also keep in mind that physicists use $SO^+(n,1)$ to denote the identity component  of $O(n,1)$. Oh, well...

To get this off the "unanswered list." Canary is simply wrong when he says that $O_o(n,1)$ is the isometry group of the hyperbolic space. The group $O_o(n,1)$ is just the (unique) index 2 subgroup in the full isometry group, consisting of orientation-preserving isometries. To see that the two groups are different, take, for instance, the reflection in the hyperplane $x_1=0$. It will be an element of $O^+(n,1)$ which is not in $O_o(n,1)$.
